# Dynamically inserted Element within Polymer Element not Visible

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Within the `ready()` method of a custom polymer element, I am creating a new element and dynamically inserting it. Even though it is seen to be part of the Shadow DOM, it is not visible on the page.

What could be the explanation and how to solve this?

```
DivElement de = new DivElement();
de.text = 'new div';
de.setAttribute('id' ,'myholder');
append(de);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you add it as child instead of as part of the shadow DOM.
Use `shadowRoot.append...` instead.
If you don't have a `<content></content>` element inside your elements template, children are not displayed.